# initialize class functions but output still 0

Tags: c++, math, initialization

I am having problems with this program.  When I compile it, I intialize all of the variables based upon the users input, but the cout still shows that the problem has '0' for most of the statements and for one of the statements its a '-negative' number.  Any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
class MortgageCalc
{
protected:
    float term;
public:
    void setData(float, float, float);
    float setTerm ();
    float monthly;
    float total;
    float interest;
    int years;
    float loan;
};

void MortgageCalc::setData(float l, float i, float y)
{
   loan = l;
   interest = i;
   years = y;
   setTerm();
}

float MortgageCalc::setTerm()
{  //simple interest calculation with power calc to establish whole number translation
     term = pow((1 + ((interest/100) / 12)), (12 * years));
     return term;
}

class mPayment : public MortgageCalc
{
public:
    int monthly()
    {
        return ((loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term ) / (term - 1));
    }
};

class tPayment : public mPayment
{
public:
    int total()
    {
        return (monthly() * (years * 12));

    }
};

class iPayment : public tPayment
{
public:
    int plusInterest()
    {
        return (total() - loan);
    }
};

int main()
{
double loan(0), interest(0);
int years = 0;

MortgageCalc mort1;
    cout << "Enter the total loan amount on your mortgage loan: $";  //established loan variable
        cin >> loan;
    cout << "Enter the interest rate (in whole #'s only): ";  //establishes interest rate variable
        cin >> interest;
    cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years: "; //establishes term of payments
        cin >> years;
mort1.setData(loan, interest, years);

mPayment m;
       cout << "Monthly payment due is " << m.monthly() << "." << endl;

tPayment t;
        cout << "Total payment will be " << t.total() << "." << endl;

iPayment i;
        cout << "Total payment plus Interest will be " << i.plusInterest() << "." << endl;

return 0;
};
```

Comment: Why does `int a; a = 5; int b; cout << b;` not print 5?

Answer (score 0):

You use default constructors on those lines:

```
mPayment m;
tPayment t;
iPayment i;
```

They have no notion of previously input data held in `mort1`. You did not take care for any way to "share" or "communicate" this data.

`m`,`t`,`i` were all initialized with random data. There is no relation to `mort1`.

I won't go into details of what correct architecture here would be, but you should read about base class initialization. As a hint I'd say in your (a little weird) example you could try making this syntax work:

```
mPayment m(mort1);
```

Comment: How do I share the data between all objects in the most efficient manner?

Comment: "*I won't go into details of what correct architecture here would be*", that's a really broad topic. There is at least 5 different ways to improve your original solution. Don't care about efficiency too much for such a simple example. If you make the syntax I showed you possible, you'll be close enough. Just make sure when you create your objects you use `mort1` and make it "sensible"m and do "*read about base class initialization*".

Comment: when I update with the code you suggested, it errors on compile 'no matching call to 'mPayment::mPayment(mortgageCalc&)'  I dont think that is right

Comment: It is. I haven't said it will work, I've said "*make the syntax I showed you possible*". You need to figure out how to get rid of the error. It's possible to make it work.

Comment: @haynstyle In this program, you don't; the thing you're trying to do is not really something that makes sense. `m`, `t`, `i` and `mort1` are completely different objects. If I have a car, and an aeroplane, if I fill my car with petrol and then look at the fuel gauge in the aeroplane I should not be surprised that it says it has 0 fuel.

Comment: I dont understand why it doesnt make sense.  I have created several child classes to perform the math functions within their own class.  Each one applies inheritance to the parent and up through the base class.  the intent is to show inheritance, which I beleive that the application completes, but for some reason, everyone keeps saying that I have to initalize all of the objects within the main function.  How do I do this when I dont even know what the output will be for the math calculations???

Comment: You are mixing definitions of `type` and `instance`. Inheritance defines relation ("connection") between types, not instances. So, yes `mPayment` has access to data of `MortgageCalc`, but `m`, `t`, `i` and `mort1` do not have access to each other. Former are types, latter are instances.

Comment: @immibis, these are all child classes that all have inheritance through each other which is why I used public 'parentclass' throughout each.  So if I set it correctly it should have initialized all of the functions.

Comment: So I know its late, I just really need one suggestion on how to proceed.  luk32's suggestion of m(mort1) is great but I am in need of a bit more of a direction please.

Comment: @immibis  I just really need some help please PLEASE PLEASE   Can someone just help me with how to complete this.

Comment: @haynstyle Probably because you need to understand what a class is, and what an object is, and nobody wants to try and explain it...

Comment: Yeah well, I have rea everything I can about Class, Objects, and Inheritance.  My browser said that I viewed over 100 internet pages about the topics and yet, I still did not get the assistance I required to answer the question.  Yet interestingly enough, someone on here is too affraid of my comments and removed them rather than providing assistance.  There are alot of people in the world that learn by seeing and putting a+b=c.  When you tell someone to RTFM, you basically saying you dont give a sh*t about them or supporting them.  That's what I was told.  Not even a direction on how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are taking all different objects like `MortgageCalc mort1; mPayment m; tPayment t; iPayment i;`.
These object do not have any relation.

Example:

```
mort1 = {term, monthly, total, interest, years, loan}
```

and suppose you have initialize with 1

```
mort1 = {term=1, monthly=1, total=1, interest=1, years=1, loan=1}
```

but it doesnot impact to the m because both are stored in memory on different location.

```
m = {term=0, monthly=0, total=0, interest=0, years=0, loan=0}
```

You can check both have different base address like `cout<<&mort1<<endl<<&m;` .

Data member you have set is part of `MortgageCalc mort1` instead of `mPayment m; tPayment t;`.

You need to brush up your C++ basic's.

Comment: the problem is that I have child classess with inheritance that are performing math functions.  I am unable to set {term, Monthly, Total} because they are functions that have to be calculated first.  The int monthly needs to be initialized based upon  "return ((loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term ) / (term - 1));"    Therefore, how am I supposed to initialize that function from outside when I dont know what to initialize?